# Mathematica: ListPlot with only special points lableld & PointSize

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I tried now a couple of hours to get a 2D Listplot of the following kind.
A ListPlot data of points should have a "3rd coordinate" like time (years) running with them.
This works so far, but is just an example:

```
list={{2000,{12,6}},{2001,{13,9}},{2002,{15,12}},{2003,{19,15}},{2004,{24,20}},{2004,{31,26}}};

data=Table[{list[[k]][[2]],Text[Style[list[[k]][[1]],12,Black],list[[k]][[2]],{-2,0}]},{k,1,Length[list]}]

plot1=ListPlot[data[[All,1]],
PlotStyle->{AbsolutePointSize[7],Orange},
PlotRange->{{0,40},{0,40}},
Frame->True,
ImageSize->500
];

plot2=Graphics[data[[All,2]]];

Show[plot1,plot2]
```

But in my real data I have thousands of points, and I want only, say, every 100th data point labeled with the time marker, and every 100th point should have a different PointSize and color.
I could not do this so far.

Comment: While you wait for a better solution make a subset of the special points and plot them over the top of the set of all points with the required formatting applied as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I extracted the special values form the data and labeled it, then I used Show to overlay both plots. It worked.

Comment: I do not know how to post code in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I did what was suggested and separated the "special" points from the data. Here's a possible workaround.

```
fakedata=Table[{yrs,Flatten[{RandomInteger[40,1],RandomInteger[40,1]}]}, {yrs,2000,2100}];

data=Table[{fakedata[[k]][[2]],Text[Style[fakedata[[k]][[1]],12,Black],fakedata[[k]][[2]],{-2,0}]},{k,1,Length[fakedata]}];

plot1=ListPlot[data[[All,1]],
PlotStyle->{AbsolutePointSize[7],Blue},
PlotRange->{{-10,50},{-10,50}},
Frame->True,ImageSize->800
];

plot2=Graphics[data[[All,2]]];

Show[plot1,plot2]
```

But this labels all points. So I did the following (kind of ugly, I know...)

```
specialData=fakedata[[;;;;10]];

label=Table[{specialData[[k]][[2]],Text[Style[specialData[[k]][[1]],14,Red],specialData[[k]][[2]],{-1.5,0},Background->LightBlue]},{k,1,Length[specialData]}];

plot3=ListPlot[label[[All,1]],
PlotStyle->{AbsolutePointSize[7],Red},
PlotRange->{{-10,50},{-10,50}},
Frame->True,
ImageSize->800
];

plot4=Graphics[label[[All,2]]];

Show[plot1,plot3,plot4]
```